# How to deal with new 'App' created while the rest of the app is still running?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I encountered something that seems quite counter intuitive to me, perhaps because I'm relatively new to Android, and so I can't seem to wrap my head around it, in order to solve it.

When an app is suspended by starting clicking the home or "overview" button, its resume later is just that - it resumes from where it left off.

**BUT**

When the app is suspended by clicking the back button, it later resumes by calling `LoadApplication(new App());` again in MainActivity. Which means that any initialization that occurs inside `App` - can interfere with all the other variables (think mainly: static variables) that are still existent. (And what about the old `App`? Does it get recycled, or do we get a resources leak?)

**SO**

How should this be dealt with? Should I refactor all of my code to have next to nothing in `App`? Or am I seeing some bug in my specific phone? As I said, this goes against what I've "known" that `App` was the "top" of the application, so I can't figure out what's happening here.

**Code to clarify the point:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    bool b = Test1.B;//false the first time, true after "back" and resuming.

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Test1.B = true;
        MainPage = new Testbed.MainPage();
    }     
}

class Test1
{
    public static bool B = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me explain what's happening.  When someone hits back, your Activity calls finish()  (Maybe Xamarin doesn't call them Activities?  Regardless of if it does or not, they exist and it has one).  That ends the Activity.  When you hit home, finish is not called, your Activity is not ended, and it is still running, just not active (think of it like hitting the minimize button on the PC).

Whenever your app is not the active app (not on screen), Android may kill it if it needs the resources.  It kills apps by a priority system.  An app with no running Activities is more likely to be killed than one that has an running Activity.  But the framework may kill either app at any time-  or never kill them and let them run forever.  So while hitting the home button makes it less likely to be killed, it doesn't prevent it either.

(Note that when this happens, all memory and resources used by your app are freed-  the process is totally killed).

Your app needs to be written so that it can be killed at any time and reinitialize itself afterwards.  This is done by writing state to Bundles in onSaveInstanceState, reading it in onResumeInstanceState, and writing data downloaded from the network to disk rather than just keeping it in memory.  Or by deciding you just don't care and users will need to start from a blank state (which is a totally acceptable for some apps).

Hopefully that clears things up a bit.

Comment: You say both: `When someone hits back, your Activity calls finish()` and `When you hit back, finish is not called` - is the difference between "someone" and "you"?

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to say when you hit home on the second. I'll edit it

Comment: `Android may kill it if it needs the resources` - this is not what I'm seeing here. If the app is killed - that's fine. What's happening here is that the app is _not_ killed - all classes etc. remain. The only thing that happens is that a new `App` class is instantiated - which then tries to initialize already initialized classes.

Comment: OK. With the edit it makes sense. But still not my case. As I said in my previous comment - the problem is that the "app" is _not_ killed. Did you try my code? (Perhaps the error is in Xamarin, and if you try it in Java it won't act like this?)

Comment: Something in your question is confusing me-  you say "it later resumes by calling LoadApplication(new App()); again in MainActivity".  Why would you ever be creating an Application?  Unless Xamarin just does something really weird, an Application is created for you by Android-  you NEVER create it.

Comment: Checking the Xamarin docs seems to confirm-  Application is a read only property-  you shouldn't be creating one via new ever.

Comment: @ispiro Your `App` class is a `Xamarin.Forms` `Application` subclass, *not* an Android `Application` subclass. When you are using `Xamarin.Forms` within Android to create your UI, you are dealing with TWO life cycle systems, Android and Xamarin.Forms : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/app-lifecycle/

Comment: @GabeSechan SushiHangover seems to be correct - the App that is created in MainActivity (not code that I wrote, it's built in) derives from Xamarin.Forms.Application. My question still stands, though.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. You're correct that Application is Xamarin.Forms Application there. Thanks. My question still stands, though - How do we deal with this strange thing - a new `App` being created while everything remains intact?

Comment: @ispiro That makes the question trivial.  You're building that App class in your onCreate, right?  If you hit back, the original Activity was finished(), so a new one was created, starting with onCreate.  If you hit home, it wasn't.  You got lucky and it wasn't killed for resources, so it was just restarted rather than recreated.  This is standard Android lifecycle stuff.  If you want to assure its created only once, make it a standard singleton or put it in the Android Application.

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried creating the singleton in both MainActivity (which I expected to fail because a new one is created) and in a class with one static property - the singleton `App`. In the second case Visual Studio started and then stopped debugging with no message.

Comment: @ispiro if you're creating it in onCreate, you aren't making a singleton, you're making an activity level variable. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx